# How to attach multiple files dynamically in laravel mail send

Tags: laravel, email

```html
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

    $message->attach($pathToFile);
});
```

when i write foreach loop for this $message->attach($pathToFile); then i get error undefine foreach:

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');
    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');
    foreach ($this->quote_fileattache_results as $key => $value) {
        $message->attach(public_path('/upload/quote/') . $value->filen‌​ame); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're trying to use foreach?

Comment: Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
            $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

            $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');
            
            foreach ($this->quote_fileattache_results as $key => $value) {
              $message->attach(public_path('/upload/quote/').$value->filename);
            }
            
        });

Comment: @Divyesh Please edit your question instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try like following to attach multiple files

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) use ($pathToFile)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

    for ($i=0; $i < count($pathToFile); $i++) {
        $message->attach($pathToFile[$i]);
    }
});
```

Hope this will help.